# Installation problem concerning "ubi-partman"

Tags: software-installation

I have a problem with installing Ubuntu. When I try to install it, it shows me this message:

```
ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog/
```

Where I can find this failure or how can I continue the installation process?

Comment: The following post may be helpful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1498417

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/220543/installation-problem-concerning-ubi-partman/220551

Answer (score 1):

Which way did you use to install it on your machine ? Via CD or a flash drive

Are you sure sure the downloaded (ISO) file has not been corrupted ?
Try to you check the MD5 sum of the ISOs if you can.

Try to redo the installation.

if that occurs again, do this :
   1. Start the desktop cd
   2. Choose "Try without installing"
   3. From the live environment, start the installation

These are some threads that might help you :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1766773 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/527848